# Character return function pointer C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, character

thanks for reading, my question is if this is properly coded:

test1.cpp:

```
void Load(OBJECTSTRUCT* gObj)
{
    char * VipType = VipTypeCheck(gObj->m_Index);
    MsgOutput(gObj->m_Index,"[%s] Welcome",VipType);
}
```

test2.cpp:

```
char* VipTypeCheck(int aIndex)
{
    switch (VipSystem[aIndex].VIP_Type)
    {
    case 0:
        return "Regular";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "Bronze";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "Gold";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "Diamond";
        break;
    default:
        return "[Error]";
        break;
    }
    return "[Error]";
}
```

It works, but my question is, could that lead to a segmentation fault/stack overflow or any other kind of error? i know i haven't allocated dynamic memory, but my doubt if the variable char *VipType is okay. Thanks, and sorry about the noob question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do pointers to string literals remain valid after a function returns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588976/do-pointers-to-string-literals-remain-valid-after-a-function-returns)

Comment: You don't really need a break after a return in a switch.  A lot of compilers will warn about that.

Answer (score 3):

You are good - you are returning a pointer to a const static string that is allocated for the life of the program.

You may want to change the return type as `const char *` because technically the string are unmodifiable.

The pointers are good for the life of the program because the compiler puts these into an area that is guaranteed to exist for the life of the program.

The reasons they are unmodifiable is because the compiler may get clever and realise that in two places you return `[Error]` and notice the are the same and use the same pointer for both - so modifying it could cause a logic error because one func expects it to be the same and the other does not

Answer (score 1):

- You need to add a prototype for `VipTypeCheck` in the `test1.cpp`
- The `VipTypeCheck` function should return `const char *` instead of `char *`
- The variable `VipType` should also be of type `const char *`

Other than that, you should be OK: returning character pointers to string literals is OK, because they are not local to the function returning them.

Also consider simplifying your function using an array, like this:

```
const char *VipTypes[] = {
    "Regular", "Bronze", "Gold", "Diamond"
};
const char * VipTypeCheck(unsigned int i) {
    return i < 4 ? VipTypes[i] : "[Error]";
}
```

Comment: Making it an array could cause out-of-bound issues - the switch statement IMHO is better because it will always work

Comment: @AdrianCornish That's what the conditional is for (also note the unsigned type, eliminating the possibility of negative indexes).