# Return a const char* literal string from a constexpr function

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have some convenience `constexpr` functions for the purpose of representing a chess board. For the sake of logging easily readable results I made a function that converts power of two representations of pieces to `const char*`

I am not certain if it is safe to have a `constexpr const char*` function return string literals, are there any problems with the below? As far as I know the compiler would replace say:

```
::std::cout << "Before: " << typePrint(bounds())
```

With:

```
::std::cout << "Before: " << "Bounds"
```

**Code**:

```
constexpr unsigned int bounds()  { return 1;       }
constexpr unsigned int nothing() { return 1 << 1;  }
constexpr unsigned int bPawn()   { return 1 << 2;  }
constexpr unsigned int bRook()   { return 1 << 3;  }
constexpr unsigned int bKnight() { return 1 << 4;  }
constexpr unsigned int bBishop() { return 1 << 5;  }
constexpr unsigned int bQueen()  { return 1 << 6;  }
constexpr unsigned int bKing()   { return 1 << 7;  }
constexpr unsigned int wPawn()   { return 1 << 8;  }
constexpr unsigned int wRook()   { return 1 << 9;  }
constexpr unsigned int wKnight() { return 1 << 10; }
constexpr unsigned int wBishop() { return 1 << 11; }
constexpr unsigned int wQueen()  { return 1 << 12; }
constexpr unsigned int wKing()   { return 1 << 13; }

constexpr const char* typePrint(const unsigned int ac_type) {
    return ac_type == bounds()  ? "Bounds" :
           ac_type == nothing() ? "Nothing" :
           ac_type == bPawn()   ? "Black Pawn" :
           ac_type == bRook()   ? "Black Rook" :
           ac_type == bKnight() ? "Black Knight" :
           ac_type == bBishop() ? "Black Bishop" :
           ac_type == bQueen()  ? "Black Queen" :
           ac_type == bKing()   ? "Black King" :
           ac_type == wPawn()   ? "White Pawn" :
           ac_type == wRook()   ? "White Rook" :
           ac_type == wKnight() ? "White Knight" :
           ac_type == wBishop() ? "White Bishop" :
           ac_type == wQueen()  ? "White Queen" :
           ac_type == wKing()   ? "White King" :
           "Unknown";
}
```

**Edit**: Something that caught my attention is that it is valid C++ to do the following:

```
::std::cout << "Before: " "Bounds";
```

However the `constexpr` returning a `const char*` is not a valid replacement and so I do not believe the compiler literally replaces `typePrint(bounds())` with `"Bounds"`, below is an error:

```
::std::cout << "Before: " typePrint(bounds());
```

Comment: That's what I would think too.

Comment: "Is it safe?" is an interesting question, but more practically speaking is "Does it work?"  Have you tried it?

Comment: @RyanBemrose, Yes, it appears to work. Although in my experience "appears to work" is a poor indication of some deep UB

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Of course you can `return` a string literal as a `const char *` from a `constexpr` function. Just like from any other function. But as you say, you cannot use a `constexpr` value like a literal so implicit concatenation does not work.

Comment: @5gon12eder, Could you explain further (or make an answer)? In general a pointer to a local variable is problematic in C++, do string literals or `constexpr` string literals avoid this problem?

Comment: Regarding your edit, `constexpr` is not macro expansion. Concatenation by juxtaposition only works with string literals. `typePrint(bounds())` is not a literal at all.

Comment: @asimes It's not pointing to a local variable.  It's pointing to static memory in the `data` segment, which is available anywhere in that process.

Comment: @asimes String literals are allocated statically an remain valid for the entire life-time of your program. It is totally safe to `return` (a pointer (in)to) them. Whether the function is `constexpr` or not doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @5gon12eder, Ok, then that solves the problem

Comment: This question (well, the answers) discuss this in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588976/do-pointers-to-string-literals-remain-valid-after-a-function-returns

Comment: @5gon12eder, Thank you. I guess the appropriate thing to do is make this a duplicate of your link

Comment: @asimes Yes, thanks for confirming.